# youtube api v3 - get videos from a playlist with view count data ordered by number of views

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, query-string, http-get

I want to get all the videos from a playlist with `statistics` data like `viewCount` and the videos should be ordered by number of video views. So far I have managed the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&key={YOUR_KEY_HERE}&maxResults=50
```

In the youtube api v2 we can pass `part=statistics` to get the view count but this is not working with v3 playlists. How can I get the above the video data in the above mentioned format.

Comment: For whatever reason playlistItems in v3 do not provide things like statistics or category. You'll have to take the video IDs returned and make another call to /v3/videos to get those. :(

Answer (score 11):

From the results of [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) call, collect the video ids, make a comma-separated list and set it as id parameter of [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call. That call will give you the data you need.