# How to get YouTube video view count between two specific dates?

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to display the top 100 YouTube video from my site, `orderby` view count but the condition is I want to display weekly based video means.

For example: `sep-26 to oct-2` is one week and I want to display the top 100 video order by view count in `sep-26 to oct-2` week means highest view count video in week display first.

So is there any API for YouTube that provides weekly view count for specific video or view count between specific date?

Below code is for get `viewcount` for specific video by `id`

```
 <?php
                $video_ID = '7lCDEYXw3mM';
                $JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$video_ID}&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=statistics");
                $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
                $statatistic = $JSON_Data->items[0]->statistics;
                $views = $statatistic->viewCount;
                echo $views;
            ?>
```

Is there any code available that gives me view count between specific dates? Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API doesn't offer that data, but how about this:

1. Every day request the top 100 videos and store the IDs, date and viewCounts locally.
2. After a week, then you can compare the viewCounts from today to the viewCounts a week ago.
3. Delete any local data older than 1 week.

Drawback: Top 100 videos of today will be (slightly?) different than top 100 videos a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to get the list of videos from the channel and then get the [`contentDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails) of every item as stated in the [answer in SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24348685/5832311).

Sample request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics&id=TruIq5IxuiU,-VoFbH8jTzE,RPNDXrAvAMg,gmQmYc9-zcg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can also check this related SO question: [youtube api v3 - get videos from a playlist with view count data ordered by number of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389137/youtube-api-v3-get-videos-from-a-playlist-with-view-count-data-ordered-by-numb)

> From the results of [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) call, collect the video ids, make a comma-separated list and set it as id parameter of [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call. That call will give you the data you need.

Hope this helps!